# How to show a div on several places(divs)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to share a single Div at several different divs without repeating code ?

For example I have a Hello World div, I want to show it at the top of the page and then at the bottom of them page again, maybe in different tab > div > bodys as well.

I am planning to do something like this **but my content is different for each tab**, 
http://codepen.io/palimadra/pen/Fryix

Here is my planned div,

```
    <div id="message" class="no-content">
        <asp:Label ID="lblnocontent" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, what is the question? Are you asking should you render the divs already server side and hide them with css and show them when needed or should you add them dynamically in javascript? Both have pros and cons.

Comment: *"Add div I want to add to each div"* wait, what..? "I want to show/hide a message in 4 `<div>s`, should i hard code the message content in each div or dynamically inject it using script" would've been better understandable in my opinion. care to edit..? or should i proceed..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy will edit it now, you caught me right, thanks

Comment: update it again, please reopen it :)